# Two Dimensional Connect Wall

Tags: connect-wall

Arrange the following nine words into a 3x3 grid, such that each row AND each column forms a connected group.

|  | ? | ? | ? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ? | strawberry | watermelon | diamond |
| ? | platinum | world | ice |
| ? | olive | alcohol | orange |

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think a possible grid is:

> `STRAWBERRY`  `WATERMELON`    `ORANGE`  
>        `ICE`        `OLIVE`       `ALCOHOL` 
>     `PLATINUM`      `WORLD`      `DIAMOND`

The rows:

> **fruit**: strawberry, watermelon, orange
>  **Martini ingredients**: ice, olive, alcohol
>  **... record**: platinum, world, diamond

The columns**:

> **... blond**: strawberry, ice, platinum
>  **ellipsoids**: watermelon, olive, world
>  **blood ...**: orange, alcohol, diamond

Comment: Pbatengf, lbh tbg vg. V npghnyyl vagraqrq gur guveq ebj gb or Fgne Cyngvahz, Penml Qvnzbaq naq Gur Jbeyq (WbWb fgnaqf) ohg 'k erpbeq' nyfb jbexf